# Bind for 0.0.0.0:50000 failed: port is already allocated on MacOS

Tags: docker-compose, jira, cicd

I initially ran jenkins in a docker container through my MacOS terminal successfully after running docker-compose up which generated the long admin password cypher. However after I restarted my machine, the setup vanished. But each time I run docker-compose up after exposing jenkins port 8080 on port 8082 and Jira port 50000 on port 200000 having tried exposing them externally on other ports previously, I keep getting the error below:

**Creating jenkins ... error

ERROR: for jenkins  Cannot start service jenkins: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jenkins (****************************************************): Bind for 0.0.0.0:20000 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for jenkins  Cannot start service jenkins: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jenkins (****************************************************): Bind for 0.0.0.0:20000 failed: port is already allocated**

I have stopped, killed and removed all containers, removed all images and pruned all networks, but nothing seems to work.

What's a way around this and how do I free up allocated ports?

Comment: netstat might help you find out what is listening on that port

Comment: @Psi is there an actual combination that could run port-specific diagnosis and show what's going on? I just ran netstat in the terminal and it's shown a lot of info most of which isn't specific to the issue at hand. WIll appreciate a resource that covers it or a combination you are familiar with.

Comment: read the manpage for netstat, there are a lot of switches that can limit the results and show only actively listening processes

Answer (score 1):

You can find the process that is running on port 20000 using:

**`lsof`**:

```
lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep <port-number>
```

or

**`netstat`**:

```
netstat -anv | grep <port-number>
```

It is probably just an old process that stays as zombie. Just kill that process (you can use `kill -9 <pid>`) and try the same operation again.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both yesterday but nothing came up.
Also reset and restarted docker daemon, but the error still persists.

Comment: you should do it on the host machine, not within the container